# Is there a way to show the Google Analytics panel inside a drupal site?

Tags: nodes, google-analytics, log-messages

I'm using the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to track the visits.

Is there a way to show the Google Analytics panel inside the Drupal site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google analytics reports](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) Provide you a default report page. You can use the Query hooks to make your own query and show it as a block or panel.

They provide common queries like visits, Top pages viewed etc.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.